# How to store a 'global var' on the eventbus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning vueJs, and i need to store a counter on my eventBus.
Basicly i need this approach because i am using that counter in multiple sibling components, and i need to access the eventBus change the counter and waneaver i want acces the counter, i can't find docs related to this, basicly i need something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

export const quoteBus = new Vue(
 data:function(){
  return {
     counter:0
   }
 }

);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

i don't know if that is the right approach to set a initial value to the counter, but i imagine something like that and then access and change the counter as i want, i need to know how i can change that value and set and get the counter property on the eventBus, i am using webkit template-simple.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are on the brink of turning your system into spaghetti code. You're already using an event bus, which is a cousin to global variables, and now you want to add a global variable to it.

The normal architecture of a Vue app is "[props down, events up](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)". Since you have a master Vue already, you should consider whether you really need to use an eventbus, rather than the more disciplined normal approach. Since you are in the process of learning Vue, you should lean heavily toward doing things in the prescribed way.

The counter should exist in the top-level Vue and be passed to components via props. The components should issue events that the top-level Vue will act on, making the appropriate changes to the counter, and Vue will propagate those changes back down to the components.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, so is it good practice to create something like a manager? a empty component that has some atributes that will be used in the children components, sorry if this is a stupid question, but i want to know.

Comment: If by "empty", you mean it has no template, I can't see how that would be useful. How would its child components ever show up?

Comment: i already get it, it should not be empty, it can work as a container for the other component as a parent and there should be the global logic of my application, thank you for your tips, very useful !